# VBA Protection Password in Mac Office 2011 Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macos

When I set VBA Protection Password of an spreadsheet (.xls) in  MS Excel 2003, I cannot unprotect it when I opened it in Mac Office 2011 Excel. It keeps saying Invalid Password.

Any idea for that???

Comment: Don't set a password? :)

Answer (score 3):

The digital signing used on Windows versions of Office is not compatible with the Mac versions of Office.  Therefore you won't be able to set a VBA password in the Windows version and unlock it on the Mac.

Try setting the password in the Mac version of Excel first and it should unlock in Windows.  As long as you are aware that locking the VBA project won't stop someone with a bit of know how from getting in anyway.

For more information on the digital certificates, see here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/does-excel-2011-support-digitally-signing-a-macro/9fe660c0-98af-4220-9f0d-dc11c56e3af0?msgId=45d02f39-4ceb-4655-b09e-c7d1e4f3f9bb